# How to enable an inspection to warn on casting Objects to primitives, ie warn when a method uses int but an Integer is passed to it

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Ok, the title is pretty straight forward, I want to be warned when I call a method:

```
private static void doSomething(int i){
//code
}
```

with

```
Integer iMightBeNull = null;
doSomething(iMightBeNull);
```

This will always give a `java.lang.NullPointerException`, which is the underlying reason.

But in java inspections, the only thing I found only "Numeric cast looses precision" -not applicable because they have the same precision, "Unnecessary numeric cast" -warns on the opposite, "Implicit numeric conversion" -gives warning on passing int to a long method,  "Overly strong type cast" -gives warning if casting child object to grandparent when just parent is enough.

Comment: I think [SpotBugs](https://spotbugs.github.io/) does this.

Comment: Do you mean javac warnings? Or intellij inspections? Or static code analysis tools in general?

Comment: intellij inspections

Comment: This way I can notice when a null is passed by accident and just make a second method using Integer that can handle null values

Comment: @VladimirVagaytsev That is not a duplicate of this question; the OP is asking if there is an inspection in IntelliJ that detects these type of problems. The OP is not asking what a NullPointerException is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really didn't wish to answer my own question and hoped to give some booty to someone else, but without further ado:

**'Auto-unboxing' highlights when casting Integer to int (or Boolean to boolean, or Long to long etc.)**

Also a few more on this topic (warning when a method meant for a type is used on another similar type) :

- 'Implicit numeric conversion' highlights when casting int to long or long to int
- 'Auto-boxing'   highlights when casting int to Integer

Answer (score 1):

The "Constant conditions and exceptions" inspection, which is enabled by default, reports a warning on this code: "Unboxing of iMightBeNull may produce 'NullPointerException'".

Comment: Unfortunately this method only works if the supplied Integer is created locally, if it is returned by another method then the inspection considers it to be A-OK

Comment: If you annotate that other method as `@Nullable`, this will be highlighted too.